# Strange characters title when post to Blogspot via Email

Tags: c#, vb.net, email, send, blogspot

When i post to blogspot via email by SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage), the title of post have some strange characters like that b���n (bạn).

[Image for detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNZ7N.png)

They are Vietnamese.
The content is ok. Just title of post get this problem.
When i post by regular sending email in Webbrowser everything is right. This is my code (VB.NET)

```
MyMailMessage.To.Add(ToEmail)
MyMailMessage.Subject = TieuDe.Trim
MyMailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
MyMailMessage.Body = NoiDung 
SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage)
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution. Down .net 4.5 to 3.5.

Comment: It should function in .Net 4.6.1.